# How to get all of the related posts on single or multiple subjects

Tags: feature-request, support

I want to query Stack Overflow for all the posts on a single subject with accepted answers. For example, I want is to get all the posts on Stack Overflow which were related to PHP [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). I saw somebody post a link in a reply and that link contains all the related posts. How do they do it and can I do it or are they operators on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `hasaccepted` search keyword to search for questions with accepted answers, and you can search `[tagname]` to search on any tagname!

So, to search for all questions in  [php-pdo](/questions/tagged/php-pdo) with accepted answers you'd use:

> [php-pdo] hasaccepted:1

as your search keywords

[here's the whole list of search keywords (for meta)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=)

[and the same for the main site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=)

**edit**: Or, if you're asking how to post a tag like this one: [pdo](/questions/tagged/pdo) then you simply use `[tag:pdo]` and markdown will convert it.